# Batch File para acessar multiplos diretórios e executar python script em diferentes command prompts

Tags: python, windows, batch

Olá pessoal tudo bem? Estou tentando criar um bat file para executar scripts python em diretórios diferentes, algo assim:

```
 C:\Test
    | --- Test1\example.py
    | --- Test2\example.py
    | --- Test3\example.py
 | --run.bat
```

Eu tenho várias pastas dentro de Test, 'Test1', 'Test2' e 'Test3', eu preciso executá-los simultaneamente com diferentes prompts de comando, Eu consegui algo assim:

```
@echo off
set back=%cd%
for /d %%i in (C:\Test\*) do (
start
cd "%%i"
python example.py
pause
cd %back%
)
```

Mas ele executa somente um script e volta para o diretório inicial, pelo que notei, acredito que ele esteja rodando o for somente no primeiro diretório, alguma sugestão para esse problema?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui resolver esse problema, segue o código do .bat criado:

```
@echo off
echo "this is the main batch script"
for /d %%i in (C:\Test\*) do (
start python "%%i\example.py"
)
pause
```